# Создание независимых объектов класса с полем-словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть следующий класс:

```
class SearchConfig:
    rooms = [1, 2, 3]
    # default: all Stations of any Lines are set to False
    metro_stations = {line: [False] * len(MetroLines.stations[line]) for line in range(len(MetroLines.stations))}
```

Класс `MetroLines` объявлен в другом файле и значения не имеет.
По итогу поле `metro_stations` содержит словарь следующего вида:

```
{0: [False, False, False], 1: [False, False, False]}
```

Я пробую создать объект класса `SearchConfig` следующим образом:

```
obj1 = SearchConfig()
obj2 = SearchConfig()
```

Далее я пробую менять поля объектов `obj1, obj2`:

```
obj2.metro_stations.get(0)[2] = True
```

Далее делаю вывод в консоль:

```
print(obj1.metro_stations)
print(obj2.metro_stations)
```

И в консоли получаю результат:

```
{0: [False, False, True], 1: [False, False, True]}
```

Почему?? Поле `test` можно изменять в обоих объектах независимо, а вот словарь не получается. Как инициализировать словарь так, чтобы его можно было менять в объектах, не мешая другим объектам?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, есть классы (типы) и есть объекты.

У тех и других есть свойства. Свойства объектов доступны только им, а свойства классов доступны и самим классам, и объектам тех классов.

В этом примере `abc` - свойство класса `Foo`, а `qwerty` - свойство объектов класса, например `self` говорит о том, что это принадлежит текущему объекту.

```
class Foo:
    abc = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.qwerty = "qwerty"

f1 = Foo()
f1.qwerty  # свойство объекта f1
f1.abc     # свойство класса Foo

f2 = Foo()
f2.qwerty  # свойство объекта f2
f2.abc     # свойство класса Foo

Foo.abc    # свойство класса Foo
Foo.qwerty # ошибка, у класса Foo нет свойства qwerty
```

Это первый момент.

Второй, это то, что есть объекты, а есть ссылки на объекты.

Когда вы написали так:

```
abc = [1, 2, 3]
zxc = abc
```

То скопировали не объект, а ссылку на него, поэтому обращение к методам объекта, могут его изменить, например `zxc.append(4)` добавит в объект новое значение.

А теперь давайте соберем все информацию воедино.

Когда вы написали:

```
class SearchConfig:
    test = 0
    metro_stations = dict()
```

То у класса `SearchConfig` создали 2 свойства, `test` и `metro_stations` и когда у `SearchConfig` или его объектов изменяли `test`, то на самом деле вы переписывали значение свойства для текущей сущности наглядный пример:

```
print(SearchConfig.test)  # 0

config_1 = SearchConfig()
config_1.test = 1

print(config_1.test)      # 1
print(SearchConfig.test)  # 0

SearchConfig.test = 2
print(SearchConfig.test)  # 2
print(config_1.test)      # 1
```

Однако, когда вы обращались к `metro_stations`, то вы работали с его методами, например ``get`,` []`, которые могли изменить состояние самого объекта, а т.к. тот объект находился в свойстве класса, то обращение любого объекта к` metro_stations` вело к одному и тому же объекту.

Один и тот же объект доступен по `metro_stations`:

```
config_1 = SearchConfig()
config_2 = SearchConfig()

print(id(SearchConfig.metro_stations))
print(id(config_1.metro_stations))
print(id(config_2.metro_stations))
```

И изменение свойства меняло объект:

```
print(SearchConfig.metro_stations)  # {}
print(config_1.metro_stations)      # {}
print(config_2.metro_stations)      # {}

SearchConfig.metro_stations[1] = 1
config_1.metro_stations.update({'abc': 123})

print(SearchConfig.metro_stations)  # {1: 1, 'abc': 123}
print(config_1.metro_stations)      # {1: 1, 'abc': 123}
print(config_2.metro_stations)      # {1: 1, 'abc': 123}
```

---

**ИТОГ.**

Создавайте свойства для объектов (в `__init__`), особенно если свойства содержат изменяемые объекты.

Пример:

```
# Заглушка, чтобы код работал
class MetroLines:
    stations = ['abc', '12']


class SearchConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 0
        self.rooms = [1, 2, 3]

        self.metro_stations = {
            i: [False] * len(x)
            for i, x in enumerate(MetroLines.stations)
        }


obj1 = SearchConfig()
obj2 = SearchConfig()

obj2.metro_stations.get(0)[2] = True

print(obj1.metro_stations)  # {0: [False, False, False], 1: [False, False]}
print(obj2.metro_stations)  # {0: [False, False, True], 1: [False, False]}
```

Comment: @mkkik, точно, классическая ошибка копипасты :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на вопрос.

```
class SearchConfig:
    test = 0
    rooms = [1, 2, 3]
    # default: all Stations of any Lines are set to False
    metro_stations = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.metro_stations = {line: [False] * len(MetroLines.stations[line])
                               for line in range(len(MetroLines.stations))}
```

Python никогда не копирует объекты неявно. Когда вы устанавливаете dict2 = dict1, вы заставляете их ссылаться на один и тот же точный объект dict, поэтому, когда вы его мутируете, все ссылки на него продолжают ссылаться на объект в его текущем состоянии.

Если вы хотите скопировать dict (что редко), вы должны сделать это явно с помощью
`dict2 = dict(dict1)` или `dict2 = dict1.copy()`

В данном случае, чтобы это удобно сделать прописав метод `__init__`, который вызывается при создании каждого объекта.

Т.о. удалось "отвязать" один объект от другого.

Comment: Если кто-то может расширить или уточнить ответ, буду благодарен.

Comment: Я сделал, будет благодарность? :D